# SQL Server query plan caching and programmatic retrieval

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a .NET client application that runs a SQL query, and that query is timed out by ADO.NET occasionally. When it times out, I can't see a query plan being cached in dm_exec_query_stats. If the query completes, then the plan *is* cached.

In my application exception handler, I'd like to programmatically capture the query plan of a particular class of queries that times out - this will help me troubleshoot. Is this possible? Since each potentially timing-out query references a table with a unique name, I can scan the query text to find the appropriate plan.

I was hoping, in my exception handler, to be able to run:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 p.query_plan, t.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.plan_handle) AS t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) AS p
WHERE t.text LIKE '%UNIQUETABLE%'
ORDER BY last_execution_time DESC;
```

But this doesn't contain the query I'm looking for - presumably because it was timed out?

Is it possible to retrieve the query plan that was used to start a query that was then aborted?

(The SQL being executed is dynamic; life would be easier with a stored procedure but sadly that's not available!)

Comment: Maybe statistics generation timed out so that no plan could be generated.

Comment: May be increase of command timeout would solve your issue. And in the application, make a call asynchronously. I know all about building dynamic queries. And yet, you can reformat, the way it is compiled in your code.

Comment: Btw, you can test my theory by profiling all statement executed events. Statistics generation manifests itself as a strange internal query.

Comment: @usr it's a nice idea, but I can replicate the non-recording of the query plan on a tiny local DB instance, so it feels unlikely to be that?

Comment: I guess so, this is probably not it if the DB is very small. Lacking other ideas I'd still look into the profiler output.

Answer (score 1):

Is your database possibly optimized for ad hoc workloads?

```
sp_CONFIGURE 'optimize for ad hoc workloads'
```

Comment: Good idea - but I turned on advanced options and had a look, but it wasn't. I've a feeling that SQL Server doesn't write a cached plan if the first execution of a given query is aborted. But Books Online isn't informative on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the query plan:

```
SELECT cplan.usecounts, 
       cplan.objtype, 
       qtext.text, 
       qplan.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cplan
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS qtext
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qplan
     WHERE qtext.text LIKE '%UniqueName%'
ORDER BY cplan.usecounts DESC;
```

And here you can list those who are timed out:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'),  QueryPlans 
AS  ( 
SELECT  RelOp.pln.value(N'@StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason', N'varchar(50)') AS TerminationReason, 
        RelOp.pln.value(N'@StatementOptmLevel', N'varchar(50)') AS OptimizationLevel, 
        --dest.text, 
        SUBSTRING(dest.text, (deqs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, 
                  (deqs.statement_end_offset - deqs.statement_start_offset) 
                  / 2 + 1) AS StatementText, 
        deqp.query_plan, 
        deqp.dbid, 
        deqs.execution_count, 
        deqs.total_elapsed_time, 
        deqs.total_logical_reads, 
        deqs.total_logical_writes 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs 
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest 
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(deqs.plan_handle) AS deqp 
        CROSS APPLY deqp.query_plan.nodes(N'//StmtSimple') RelOp (pln) 
WHERE   deqs.statement_end_offset > -1        
)   
SELECT  DB_NAME(qp.dbid), 
        * 
FROM    QueryPlans AS qp 
WHERE   qp.TerminationReason = 'Timeout' 
ORDER BY qp.execution_count DESC ;
```